# In storm, my topology is failing after certain number of acknowledgements

Tags: apache-storm

I have a cluster with one nimbus( dual core, 4GB) and 3 supervisors (dual core, 4GB) each. The parallelism is 1,4,1

Comment: 1 spout, 4 logic bolts, 1 write bolt

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance your topology uses too much memory and your worker.childopts settings are too low?

Have you monitored the topology resources (e.g. through "top" or through a profiler) and see what happens when it "fails"?

Comment: no, 
now I am able to run the topology but my max spout pending is 200, but its taking too much of time( 44 hours to process 14 lacs input pairs)

Comment: I want to speed up the topology so that it can process the complete input in less than 10 hours